# Hybrid app. The camera does not open to capture photo

Tags: android, html, cordova, mobile

I have a mobile application in HTML5 and Javascript, builded with PhoneGap in which there is a script that works taking captures from the camera. It works correctly in browsers, it asks for permission to use the camera, but it gives authorization error from the apk.
The script:

```
https://pixlcore.com/demos/webcamjs/demos/basic.html
```

I have configured the AndroidManifest.xml and the config.xml and I have placed the HTML5 Accept and Capture tags.
My question is whether this failure can be due to the javascript code or there is something I am not understanding about the permissions and preferences.
This is the manifest:

```
 https://github.com/kadetito/ELMUNDO/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml
```

and the config.xml:

```
 https://github.com/kadetito/ELMUNDO/blob/master/config.xml
```

Comment: Please write your question in English. :)

Comment: Your title is still in Spanish. Please post what error you are getting from cordova. Are you using an emulator? Does this happen only with Android devices? Please post your code directly in your question.

Comment: The error that returns is "Webcam.js Error: Could not access webcam. NotAllowedError: Permission denied" in alert message